# Cosa significa "pecora" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, nouns

Nel romanzo *Se una notte d'inverno un viaggiatore* d'Italo Calvino ho letto:

> Dalle macchie di calce sullo stipite, e dal berretto che s'affaccia sopra una giacca di fatica imbottita di *pecora*, hai l'impressione che il locale sia chiuso per restauri, e vi si trovi solo un imbianchino o un addetto alle pulizie.

So cos'è una pecora, comunque non riesco a capire cosa possa significare tale vocabolo in questo contesto. Ho fatto una cerca in alcuni dizionari, ma nessun significato figurato di "pecora" sembra avere senso qui. Potreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "pecora" nella frase precedente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> giacca di fatica imbottita di pecora

Ragionevolmente non è una giacca di fatica imbottita *di* pecora, ma una giacca di fatica imbottita *di pelo* di pecora; "giacca di fatica imbottita di pelo di pecora" che non è un'espressione usata per riferirsi ad un particolare tipo di giacca ma alle *qualità* della stessa giacca (di fatica e imbottita di pelo di pecora).

Tralasciando il "di fatica" che non è l'oggetto della domanda e focalizzandosi su "giacca imbottita di pecora", espressioni come questa sono molto usate in Italiano, e sono delle sineddoche<sup>[1](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/sineddoche/)</sup>; specialmente se si sta cercando di imparare l'Italiano è bene tenere a mente che esistono, per evitare di finire a cercare un'oggetto che idiomaticamente "non esiste".

Queste espressioni sono usate per riferirsi ad un oggetto citandone un altro che ha un certo tipo di relazione col primo, relazione che può essere della natura di uno dei seguenti casi (citando quelli elencati dal Treccani<sup>[1](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/sineddoche/)</sup>):

- parte / tutto
- singolare / plurale
- genere / specie
- materia prima / oggetto prodotto

In questo caso sussiste la prima (o come Walter Tross precisa anche la quarta): si indica la pecora (il tutto / la materia prima) per indicare il pelo della pecora (la parte / l'oggetto prodotto); normalmente nel primo caso si ritrova più spesso il caso contrario (ovvero la parte per il tutto), ma in una pagina del Treccani<sup>[2](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/sineddoche_(Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano)/)</sup> più approfondita si trova esplcitamente che:

> [...] Nel Novecento, per Lausberg (1969) la sineddoche consiste in «uno spostamento della denominazione della cosa che si intende sul piano del contenuto concettuale», secondo un processo in cui il significato si sposta secondo due direttrici specifiche:
>
> (a) locus a maiore ad minus «dal più al meno»: il tutto per la parte; il genere per la specie; il plurale per il singolare; il prodotto finito per la materia grezza;
>
> (b) locus a minore ad maius «dal meno al più»: la parte per il tutto; la specie per il genere; il singolare per il plurale. [...]

E che [pertanto]:

> [...] Si distinguono di solito la sineddoche generalizzante, che procede dal più al meno, e la sineddoche particolarizzante, che procede dal meno al più. Il primo tipo indica il tropo che si esercita su un concetto più generale come simbolo del concetto che vi si può includere [...]

Come esempio viene portato:

> [...] (a) il tutto per la parte: leggere la Commedia di Dante (per leggere pagine della …) [...]

Per citare un esempio per ogni tipo di relazione elencata (citando quelli elencati dal Treccani<sup>[1](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/sineddoche/)</sup>):

- singolare per il plurale: "lo straniero" per "gli stranieri"
- genere per la specie: "i mortali" per "gli uomini"
- materia prima per l'oggetto prodotto: "un bronzo" per "una scultura in bronzo"

---

<sub>1: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/sineddoche/</sub>

<sub>2: [http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/sineddoche_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/sineddoche_(Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano)/)</sub>

Comment: Sei sicuro che si tratta di una sineddoche quando si usa il tutto per indicare la parte? Io ricordavo il contrario (p. es. _cima_, come termine marinaro, per _corda_).

Comment: La relazione "materia prima / oggetto prodotto" mi pare un candidato migliore.

Comment: @WalterTross Indubbiamente il contrario è molto più diffuso; ho aggiunto come fonte un'altra pagina del Treccani, controlla l'edit; per quanto riguarda la seconda mi sembrerebbe anche a me e l'ho aggiunto alla risposta, però non so, se si passa da una "materia prima" ad un "oggetto prodotto" si passerebbe da una "materia prima" *pecora* (!) ad un' "oggetto prodotto" *pelo di pecora*.

Comment: Non nego la correlazione, e infatti l'ho aggiunto, ma mi suona un pò male, o quantomeno non definirei una pecora proprio come "materia prima" (e forse neanche il pelo di pecora come "oggetto prodotto"; piuttosto potrei dire che il pelo di pecora è la materia prima e che la giacca imbottita è l'oggetto prodotto, e quindi chiamare una giacca imbottita di pelo di pecora come "un pelo di pecora"). Comunque forse mi sbaglio io, in ogni caso l'ho aggiunto visto che almeno parzialmente ha sicuramente senso.

Comment: Il bello di StackExchange è che si impara sempre qualcosa. Cancello la mia risposta

Comment: Giacca imbottita con "lana di pecora" più che pelo di pecora. Lana https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lana